# Angular 5 : Multiple languages requesting different layouts

Tags: angular, locale, angular-template

I have an `Angular 5` application with a default language French. I have to add the arabic which requires a global layout changing (things must be displayed from right to left...).

I want to know if is there a way to use only one component and make conditional template selection. For example :

```
--my-compenent_ar.html
--my-compenent_fr.html
--my-component.ts

And in my @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: ==> condition here
    styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent
```

The current version of Angular (5) does not support this case natively.

Is there any good way to do it ?

---

What I'm thinking to do is

```
--my-compenent_ar.html
--my-compenent_fr.html
--my-component.ts
--my-component.ar.ts

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './my-compenent_fr.html'
    styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
....
}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './my-compenent_ar.html'
    styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponentAR extends MyComponent {}
```

With this configuration, `FR` locale will navigate to `MyComponent` and `AR` locale to `MyComponentAR`.

This is verbose. Do you have a clean way to do it ?

Comment: Why not use ngIf in one template?
<div *ngIf="French"> ... </div>
<div *ngIf="AR"> ... </div>

Comment: I just have quite the same situation but with role ^^ whats about put the condition in the template I know its ugly :)

Comment: There is a lot of disadvantage using *ngif. First of all, you will not be able to use lazy loading. Secondly, it's very redundante, you will have to write the logic for every component while you can use HttpClient interceptor to navigate to the correct language only once. And it's ugly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those having the same scenario, below my solution that uses only one component and supports changing layout direction.

## 1. Create routes for each language

Let's assume that my routes are :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'users',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: UsersComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':uid/profile',
                component: ProfileViewComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The idea is to prefix those routes by the supported languages. I do this dynamically as below (I only prefix with arabic language here) :

```
/**
 * Initialize language and routes
 * @param routes
 * @returns {Promise<any>}
 */
init(routes: Routes): Promise<any> {

    this.routes = routes;
    let children: Routes = [...this.routes];

    /** exclude certain routes */
    for (let i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (children[i].data && children[i].data['skipRouteLocalization']) {
            children.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    /** append children routes */
    if (children && children.length) {
        if (this.locales.length > 1) {
            this.routes.unshift({path: 'ar', children: children});
        }
    }

    return of(this.routes).toPromise();
}
```

This method is called on app initialization :

```
@Injectable()
export class ParserInitializer {
    parser: LocalizeParser;
    routes: Routes;

    /**
     * CTOR
     * @param injector
     */
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    /**
     * @returns {Promise<any>}
     */
    appInitializer(): Promise<any> {
        const res = this.parser.init(this.routes);

        res.then(() => {
            let router = this.injector.get(Router);
            router.resetConfig(this.parser.routes);
        });

        return res;
    }

    /**
     * @param parser
     * @param routes
     * @returns {()=>Promise<any>}
     */
    generateInitializer(parser: LocalizeParser, routes: Routes[]): () => Promise<any> {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.routes = routes.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
        return this.appInitializer;
    }
}

/**
 * @param p
 * @param parser
 * @param routes
 * @returns {any}
 */
export function getAppInitializer(p: ParserInitializer, parser: LocalizeParser, routes: Routes[]): any {
    return p.generateInitializer(parser, routes).bind(p);
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, TranslateModule],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
export class LocalizeRouterModule {

    static forRoot(routes: Routes, config: LocalizeRouterConfig = {}): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: LocalizeRouterModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: RAW_ROUTES,
                    multi: true,
                    useValue: routes
                },
                config.parser,
                // LocalizeParser,
                ParserInitializer,
                {
                    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                    multi: true,
                    useFactory: getAppInitializer,
                    deps: [ParserInitializer, LocalizeParser, RAW_ROUTES]
                }
            ]
        };
    }


}
```

## 2. Use Bootstrap RTL

Since arabic language requires layout direction to be from right to left, I use [RTL Boostrap support](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) to perform this. I scoped this rtl css within a `.rtl` css class and uses a angular directive to set this css class at top level when arabic is selected.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[yfLayoutClass]'
})
export class LayoutClassDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
                private renderer: Renderer2,
                private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.store.select(fromRoot.getLocale)
            .filter(loc => loc != null)
            .subscribe(locale => {

                if (locale.isArabic()) {
                    this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'rtl');
                } else {
                    this.renderer.removeClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'rtl');
                }

            });


    }

}
```

## 3. Redirect to the correct prefixed route when lang changes

When language changes, user must be redirected to the correct prefixed route. To do this dynamically, I use the following code in my `appComponent`

```
public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.translateService.onLangChange
        .combineLatest(this.router.events)
        .subscribe(([langEvent, event]) => {

            if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
                let currentUrl = event.url;

                let locale = Locale.getLocaleByShortcut(langEvent.lang);

                let queryParams = event.state.root.queryParams;

                if (locale) {
                    if (locale.isArabic()) {
                        if (!ContextUtils.isArabicUrl(currentUrl)) {
                            this.router.navigateByUrl(ContextUtils.arabizeUrl(currentUrl), {queryParams: queryParams});
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (ContextUtils.isArabicUrl(currentUrl)) {
                            this.router.navigateByUrl(ContextUtils.frenchifyUrl(currentUrl), {queryParams: queryParams});
                        }
                    }
                }

            }


        });
}
```

That's all ! Like this you only use one component.

Hope it helps !